# How to choose the earliest day in a Vector (from "Mon" to "Sun")

Tags: java

This method takes a list of dates and it returns the most frequent day within the dates. It returns correctly; however, in case of tie between the days, the earliest day should be returned. For example, if there was a tie between Tuesday and Friday, the method should return "Tue". However, I could not figure out how to do it. I figured out how to return in case of tie but not the earliest day.

```
public static String mostFrequentDayOfWeek( SimpleDate[] dates ) {
        int maxcount = 0;
        String freqDay = "";
        Vector<String> days = new Vector<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
                if (dayOfWeek(dates[i]).equals(dayOfWeek(dates[j]))) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
                freqDay = dayOfWeek(dates[i]);
            }

            else if (count == maxcount) {
                Vector<String> days;
                days = new Vector<String>();
                days.add(dayOfWeek(dates[i]));
                freqDay = days.get(i);
                
            }
        }
        return freqDay;
    }
```

This is the bit where im stuck on:

```
else if (count == maxcount) {
                
                
                days.add(dayOfWeek(dates[i]));
                freqDay = days.get(i);
                
            }
```

It's not completed but im asking if you could demonstrate a way to do it.

The code should return the earliest most frequent day in case of tie only.

This is dayOfWeeks method as requested:

```
public static String dayOfWeek( SimpleDate date ) {
        // declared vairables to utilise the getters of day, month and year in SimpleDate
        int day = date.getDay();     
        int month = date.getMonth(); 
        int year = date.getYear();   
        int Z, X, Y, W, C, D;
        String nameofday = ""; // a variable that will be returned by the method 

        if(month < 3){
            month = month + 12;
            year = year - 1;
        }
        C = year % 100;
        D = year / 100;
        W = 13*( month + 1 )/5;
        X = C / 4;
        Y = D / 4;
        Z = W + X + Y + day + C - 2 * D;
        day = Z % 7;

        if(day<0){
            day =+ 7;
        }
                // switch-case statement to switch whatever the value of 'day' to its corresponce abbreaviation
        switch(day){
            case 0 : nameofday = "Sat";break;
            case 1 : nameofday = "Sun";break;
            case 2 : nameofday = "Mon";break;
            case 3 : nameofday = "Tue";break;
            case 4 : nameofday = "Wed";break;
            case 5 : nameofday = "Thu";break;
            case 6 : nameofday = "Fri";break;
        }
        return nameofday;
    }
```

Comment: `Vector`? `SimpleDate`? Looks legacy to me.

Comment: @MCEmperor Do you mean its old?

Comment: You're declaring the Vector inside the if statement which means it has local scope. It will disappear after the if statement and new one created again on the next tie. Probably not what you intended...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks for your reply, I fixed that but what I am looking for is how to return a day from a changing vector.

Comment: Update your code above so we can see your current incarnation.

Comment: The modern classes to use are `LocalDate` for a date, `DayOfWeek` for -- what the name says -- and `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. I recommend them all.

Comment: In the `count == maxcount` case you need to determine whether `freqDay` or `dayOfWeek(dates[i])` is earlier in the week. Which is easy with `DayOfWeek`, not quite so easy with strings, but still doable if you insist.

Comment: Also show us `dayOfWeek()` as well please.

Comment: @EbrahimAl-Aghbari https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system

Comment: Explain the class `SimpleDate`. I cannot find that class bundled with Java.

Comment: Not what you asked, your algorithm looks over-complicated to me. If there are 3 Tuesdays in the array, you count them 3 times. And 5000 times if there are 5000 Tuesdays. Once should suffice. Also determining the day of week of a given date is built into Java (the `LocalDate` class mentioned, for example), you had not needed code it yourself. And keeping the day as a string is impractical.

Comment: What I would have done: If the array has length 0, return the empty string. Use an `EnumMap<DayOfWeek, Integer>` for the counts (or an array of `ìnt`). Initialize all counts to 0. Iterate once through the date array and for each day of week increment the corresponding count. Then iterate once through the counts form Monday to Sunday to find the first highest count. So when I find the same count again, ignore it because we already know it’s later in the week. Only when finding a strictly higher count, record it as the max. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dayOfWeek()` returns only one of these values:

```
{ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }
```

You could use a `List` to determine the order of them:

```
  public static String mostFrequentDayOfWeek(SimpleDate[] dates ) {
      int maxCount = 0;
      int maxIndex = 0;
      String freqDay = "";

      List<String> days = Arrays.asList("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
      for(SimpleDate d1 : dates) {
        int count = 0;
        String day1 = dayOfWeek(d1);
        for(SimpleDate d2 : dates) {
          String day2 = dayOfWeek(d2);
          if (day1.equals(day2)) {
            count++;
          }      
        }
        
        if (count > maxCount) {
          maxCount = count;
          maxIndex = days.indexOf(day1);
          freqDay = day1;
        }
        else if (count == maxCount) {
          int newIndex = days.indexOf(day1);
          if (newIndex < maxIndex) {
            maxIndex = newIndex;
            freqDay = day1;
          }
        }
      }  
    
      return freqDay;
  }
```

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: This is a bit late response, but I realised you did not use the "new" keyword when creating the days list. Is there a reason for not using it, though days is a new object?
`List<String> days = Arrays.asList("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");`

Comment: If we wanted an EMPTY list then I would have done that. In this case, I wanted the days of the week already in the list. The `Arrays.asList()` method created the list for us and returned it.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem modify `else if` block

```
else if (count == maxcount) {
    days.add(dayOfWeek(dates[i]));
    if (days.indexOf(dayOfWeek(dates[i])) < days.indexOf(freqDay)) {
        freqDay = dayOfWeek(dates[i]);
    }
}
```

modified code as below:

```
public static String mostFrequentDayOfWeek(SimpleDate[] dates) {
    int maxcount = 0;
    String freqDay = "";
    Vector<String> days = new Vector<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
            if (dayOfWeek(dates[i]).equals(dayOfWeek(dates[j]))) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > maxcount) {
            maxcount = count;
            freqDay = dayOfWeek(dates[i]);
        } else if (count == maxcount) {
            days.add(dayOfWeek(dates[i]));
            if (days.indexOf(dayOfWeek(dates[i])) < days.indexOf(freqDay)) {
                freqDay = dayOfWeek(dates[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return freqDay;
}
```